# Where to initialize the data structures : init or viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Which is the best place to initialize the data structures used to display content in my view controllers: `init` or `viewDidLoad`?

Also, for either case, where should I be releasing them: `dealloc`, `viewDidUnload` or `didReceiveMemoryWarning` ?

Comment: For the record, where UIViewController subclasses are concerned, the choice is between `initWithNibName:bundle:` and `viewDidLoad`. Plain `init` is not the designated initializer for these classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The all-encompasing answer is, "It depends upon your view lifecycle."  Each method has its own place relative to how your views will load and appear.

As a rule of thumb, though, `viewDidLoad` is a good default place to go first - your XIB views will already be instantiated so you can set their properties.  If you do a lot of loading and unloading of views, you might want to push pure data that's fairly static back to your `init` calls.

`viewWillAppear` is another option, depending again upon your views' life cycles and how much your data is likely to change while the view is hidden.

ETA: Release your memory in the complementary calls to where you allocate it.  In `dealloc`, `viewDidUnload` or `viewDidDisappear`.  `didReceiveMemoryWarning` should always unload anything you can regardless of where you initialize it, and your code should be smart enough to reload the data once it is active again.

Comment: As NJones mentions in his comment to the question above, by `init` calls I mean the designated initializer, whatever it happens to be - by default your `initWithNibName:bundle:`.  I tend to rearrange mine a bit, but that's a matter of personal style - the key thing is to be clear on what a designated initializer is (the one method that always gets called by all the other initializer calls and thus is where you do the heavy lifting in your `init` cycle).